# Coulomb potential from laplace's equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

How can I derive the equation for Coulomb Potential V(r) from the laplace's equation for electrostatic potential? $\nabla^2\psi=0$ (assuming spherical symmetry) I have no idea how i should start.

Comment: Isn't this done in textbooks on the subject of E&M?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\nabla^2 V&=0\\
\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{d}{dr}\left(r^2\frac{dV}{dr}\right)&=0\, ,\\
r^2\frac{dV}{dr}&=K\, ,\\
\vec E=-\hat r\frac{dV}{dr}&=-\hat r\,\frac{K}{r^2}\, .
\end{align}
The intermediate steps you can sort out by yourself.